# Eliminar o coger estilo html en POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

Tengo lo siguiente :

```
String cadena="<ul><li>test &nbsp;</li><li>test 2</li></ul>"

HSSFCell cell = row.createCell((short)0);
cell.setCellValue(cadena)
```

Me gustaria que la celda cogiera el formato html o en el peor de los casos que elimine el html

Comment: Te han servido nuestras respuestas de algo? al final qué hiciste? (tengo curiosidad XDD)

Comment: al final use tu solución 2, provisionalemente ya que la solución 1 no me parecia muy optimo si tengo que controlar cada caso, gracias @lois6b, por cierto tengo otra duda con poi en word que aún no logro darle solucion xD

Comment: pues ya sabes, a preguntar. HAHAH antes de tu series de preguntas yo no tenia ni idea y a base de investigar... xD

Comment: ya lo pregunte pero nadie me ha dicho nada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Para formatear el excel:**

   - [Esta es una pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18493804/apache-poi-formatting-output-to-html) similar a la tuya, cuya respuesta es ir interpretando las etiquetas para poner el formato en excel adecuado.

     Hice un demo muy *alfa* de procesar el string con regex para que coja las etiquetas y que luego en funcion de las que lea, aplicar el estilo necesario para que excel lo reconozca:

     - [DEMO](https://ideone.com/mXYLyz)
2. **Para quitar el HTML**

   1. Usar [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/)

      ```
      public static String quitarHTML(String html) {
          return Jsoup.parse(html).text();
      }
      ```
   2. Si no quieres usar librerias externas, puedes hacer uso de [regex](/questions/tagged/regex):

      ```
      public static String quitarHTML(String html) {
          return html.replaceAll("\\<.*?>","");
      }
      ```

      [DEMO](https://ideone.com/tQeHlZ)

Comment: si usas el método a la cadena que pase no funciona, reemplaza todo por "", tb comentarte que me gustaría más que cogiera el formato html la celda

Comment: @sirdaiz ya hice el demo y funciona bien ese metodo. voy a ver si en un rato intento el formato de celda.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Para eliminar las etiquetas `HTML` del `String` puedes hacer uso de la librería [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) :

```
public static String htmlATexto(String html) {
    return Jsoup.parse(html).text();
}
```

---

Si estás programando en `Android` utiliza simplemente esto:

```
android.text.Html.fromHtml(instruction).toString()
```

Comment: hahah me has adelantado en la recta final xD

Comment: @lois6b Tu respuesta es más completa al menos :')